# Creating processes in Java using Activiti

Tags: activiti

I have a requirement to create a dynamic multi level approval process for my application using activity.[process diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEu7g.jpg)

The Number of steps and parallel approvals in each step is decided at run time.
In the diagram above, the number of levels, number of concurrent approvals with within each level are defined at record creation.
I am not looking to change the process at run time, but create the process at run time.

Is this possible using Activiti?

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: You are not supposed to change processes on the fly. You can generate activiti process diagram (xml definition of process), upload it to activiti engine through rest and start process. Later you can upload new version of process (before it ends and while it is persisted, that is not actively running), and then use shamanistic techniques to switch running process to new definition... but from the start it all looks like wrong requirement.

Comment: @MartinGrofčík - sorry about that. updated the questions above.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin - I am not looking to change the process at run time, but create the process at run time. All the entities can have different workflows. The work flow needs to be defined at the initiation of a transaction. each transaction ofcourse is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not looking to change the process at run time, but create the process at run time.
>
> Is this possible using Activiti?

Yes, it is. In fact I tried both, but for completely different requirement.
https://gromar01.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/design-by-doing-with-activiti6/

I would say that for your case it is possible to cover your requirements by standard BPMN model and do not use dynamically created process models.

Comment: This is quite helpful. Thanks. I would give this a try.